# Display SpringBoot Actuator JSON string as HTML

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

How can I display the JSON string from SpringBoot Actuator as HTML?
So when I visit url localhost:8080/actuator/health
I see something like

```
Application status: UP
Database H2:        UP
Database MySQL:     UP
Diskspace:          UP
```

And if there is some errors I display them too.
Thank you

Comment: there is nothing out of the box, you need to have an endpoint of your own, which you would call, which in turn calls actuator endpoint and does the conversion from json to html

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite the existing definition for EndpointWebExtension like below. You can write custom logic as per requirement.

```
@Component

@EndpointWebExtension(endpoint = HealthEndpoint.class)

public class CustomeEndpointWebExtension extends HealthEndpointWebExtension {

    private static final String[] NO_PATH = {};
    public HealthWebEndpointWebExtension(HealthContributorRegistry registry, HealthEndpointGroups groups) {
        super(registry, groups);

    }

//To write custom logic for /acuator/health
    @ReadOperation
    public WebEndpointResponse<HealthComponent> health(ApiVersion apiVersion, SecurityContext securityContext) {
        System.out.println("#@Start");
        WebEndpointResponse<HealthComponent> health = health(apiVersion, securityContext, false, NO_PATH);
        //Can write customer logic here as per requirment
        System.out.println("#@End"+health.getBody().getStatus());
        return health;
    }

//To write custom logic for /acuator/health/db
    @ReadOperation
    public WebEndpointResponse<HealthComponent> health(ApiVersion apiVersion, SecurityContext securityContext,
            @Selector(match = Match.ALL_REMAINING) String... path) {
        WebEndpointResponse<HealthComponent> health = health(apiVersion, securityContext, false, path);
        System.out.println("#Status"+health.getBody().getStatus());
        return health;
    }

}
```

You can refer to below stack to convert json to html
[How to convert a json object into HTML format in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3630667/how-to-convert-a-json-object-into-html-format-in-java)